# Code for custom taskbar hover-over buttons?

Tags: windows-8, hover, tooltip, wtl, taskbar

Windows Vista, 7 and 8 all display a preview of the application; when the application icon of an open application is hovered over in the taskbar.

Some developers have added custom options in this tooltip, like [Windows Media Player](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Media_Player):

[image: Windows Media Player 12 tooltip]

Given an application written in C++ which uses the [Windows Template Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Template_Library), how would I code in a custom button to an application tooltip preview?

Answer (score 4):

The feature is known as [Taskbar Extensions - Thumbnail Toolbars](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#thumbbars). WTL does not provide any helper/wrapper classes to implement support for thumbnail toolbars, so you have to use the API directly, using [`ITaskbarList3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd391692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface.

Comment: I am not programming an application, I am just looking for the name of this feature. I am using windows 10 and want to see if there is a chrome plugin, or something, that enables this feature on the chrome browser for web media players. Should I look in the web with this name "Taskbar Extension"?

Comment: @santiagoarizti: it should be named along the lines of "taskbar thumbnail/buttons for media playback" I suppose.